# How to send and read data from serial port in C++

Tags: c++, arduino

I hope that someone here can help me, I want to control my arduino uno by sending it commands from a C++ program that performs some basic face recognition. It is important that i send a string of data as such

`its John;`

So that the arduino can respond correctly. However I'm struggling with finding the correct method of performing such an action. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

As a note I am NOT running this program on windows. It will be run on a raspberry pi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the raspberry pi, the serial port is the device /dev/ttyAMA0.  It might also be running a terminal, so you'll have to open up /etc/inittab and comment out this line and reboot:

```
#T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100
```

If you don't, your arduino is going to be trying to log in to your pi whenever it sends anything to the serial port.

Another trap is if you want to use binary data in your protocol, XON/XOFF flow control is enabled by default which will silently eat certain bytes (^S and ^Q).

Here's how to open, set the serial port mode (disable flow control!) and baud rate, and write to the serial port:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
// (i may be forgetting some headers)

...

int fd = open("/dev/ttyAMA0", O_RDWR);
if (fd == -1) {
  perror("/dev/ttyAMA0");
  return 1;
}

struct termios tios;
tcgetattr(fd, &tios);
// disable flow control and all that, and ignore break and parity errors
tios.c_iflag = IGNBRK | IGNPAR;
tios.c_oflag = 0;
tios.c_lflag = 0;
cfsetspeed(&tios, B9600);
tcsetattr(fd, TCSAFLUSH, &tios);

// the serial port has a brief glitch once we turn it on which generates a
// start bit; sleep for 1ms to let it settle
usleep(1000);    

// output to serial port
char msg[] = "hi there";
write(fd, msg, strlen(msg));
```

Comment: You sir are a god, I give you a metaphorical gold coin!!! Nice to have a helpful person on Stack!

Anyone that's found this from google, add the following includes to get it working all well and good.
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>